# Apache HttpClient 4.1 - Proxy Settings

Tags: java, proxy, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to POST some parameters to a server, but I need to set up the proxy. can you help me to to sort it "setting the proxy" part of my code ?

```java
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("xx.x.x.xx");

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

httpclient.getParams().setParameter("3128",proxy);


HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aranan", song));

httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println("Request Handled?: " + response.getStatusLine());

in = entity.getContent();

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes I sorted out my own problem,this line

```java
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("3128",proxy);
```

should be

```java
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);
```

**Complete Example of a Apache HttpClient 4.1, setting proxy can be found below**

```java
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("ip address",port number);
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);

HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param name", param));
httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.ISO_8859_1));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println("Request Handled?: " + response.getStatusLine());
InputStream in = entity.getContent();
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

Comment: `httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);` is deprecated

Comment: HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("ip address",port number);
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy); Works like a charm on 4.5.6

Answer (score 60):

Non deprecated way of doing it (also in 4.5.5 version) is:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.com", 80, "http");
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                    .build();
```

Comment: You should use ```new HttpHost("proxy.com", 80, HttpHost.DEFAULT_SCHEME_NAME)``` or ```new HttpHost("proxy.com", 80)```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was a little bit confused with apache commons http vs httpcomponents, now I can you both of them

Comment: Thank you for the non deprecated solution :)

Answer (score 9):

This is quick way I use to set the proxy:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;    
...
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("www.proxy.com", 8080, "http");
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setProxy(proxy).build();
```

Answer (score 6):

When I use apache httpclient v4.5.5,I found HttpClient.getParams() is deprecated in v4.3,we should use `org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig` instead.
[Code sample](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java) 
shows that:

```
 HttpHost target = new HttpHost("httpbin.org", 443, "https");
 HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8080, "http");

 RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
     .setProxy(proxy)
     .build();
 HttpGet request = new HttpGet("/");
 request.setConfig(config);
 CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, request);
```