# twitter hosebird client not working

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-hbc

I am trying to get tweets via hbc-twitter4j-v3 . Example code is : https://github.com/twitter/hbc/blob/master/hbc-example/src/main/java/com/twitter/hbc/example/Twitter4jSampleStreamExample.java
For enabling authentication on proxy, I have also set system properties for host,port and authentication. But it is showing following error-

```
[main] INFO com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.BasicClient - New connection executed: hosebird-client-0, endpoint: /1.1/statuses/sample.json?delimited=length&stall_warnings=true
[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] INFO com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - hosebird-client-0 Establishing a connection
[main] INFO com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.BasicClient - Stopping the client: hosebird-client-0, endpoint: /1.1/statuses/sample.json?delimited=length&stall_warnings=true
[main] INFO com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - hosebird-client-0 exit event - Stopped by user: waiting for 5000 ms
[main] WARN com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - hosebird-client-0 Client thread failed to finish in 5000 millis
[main] INFO com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.BasicClient - Successfully stopped the client: hosebird-client-0, endpoint: /1.1/statuses/sample.json?delimited=length&stall_warnings=true
[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] WARN com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - hosebird-client-0 Unknown host - stream.twitter.com
[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] WARN com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - hosebird-client-0 failed to establish connection properly
[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] INFO com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - hosebird-client-0 Done processing, preparing to close connection
[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] INFO com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - hosebird-client-0 Shutting down httpclient connection manager
```

Any help??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I haven't overlooked something but this is how it appears to me...

If by setting properties you mean the `http.proxy*` ones, I don't think it will work as hosebird-client uses Apache's HTTP client under the hood which doesn't seem to use them.

From a cursory glance at the code, specifically around the `ClientBuilder`, it doesn't look like hbc supports proxy configuration - perhaps they have a good reason not to or just don't need the feature themselves, maybe try requesting it?

It looks like one of the ways you can get `HttpClient` to use a proxy is by [adding it to the `HttpParams` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957144/69875), e.g.:

```
HttpParams params = ...
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(hostname, port);
params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

Whilst the `HttpParams` object isn't exposed anywhere you could potentially extend the `ClientBuilder` in order to supply your proxy configuration. If you look at the [`ClientBuilder#build()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957144/69875) method, you can see where the `HttpParams` object is being set up. Good luck!

**EDIT:** Additionally, this [issue](https://github.com/twitter/hbc/issues/90) indicates there are no plans to add proxy support directly in hbc.