# I am not able to access url over proxy seeting

Tags: java, proxy, java-5

I am try to access url over proxy setting but am not able to make connection.
I tried to get solution from google and existing stackoverflow but any thing not work for me.

IDE- Netbeans

Java- 1.5

This is my code which i am trying

```
           HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyIp, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort));
            //client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("", ""));
            PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(meterConfigXml);
            postMethod.setParameter("u", userName);
            postMethod.setParameter("p", password);
            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

but it gives exception .

```
 HttpMethodDirector - Closing the connection.
INFO  2013-12-30 16:49:48,218 [Thread-2] : HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
DEBUG 2013-12-30 16:49:48,218 [Thread-2] : HttpMethodDirector - Malformed reply from SOCKS server
java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:706)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:386)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at eltrack.src.MeterThread.saveXMLFile(Unknown Source)
    at eltrack.src.MeterThread.startProcess(Unknown Source)
    at eltrack.src.Synch.run(Synch.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
INFO  2013-12-30 16:49:48,218 [Thread-2] : HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
DEBUG 2013-12-30 16:49:48,218 [Thread-2] : HttpConnection - Open connection to 192.168.0.3:808
DEBUG 2013-12-30 16:50:05,421 [AWT-EventQueue-0] : HttpMethodDirector - Closing the connection.
INFO  2013-12-30 16:50:05,421 [AWT-EventQueue-0] : HttpMethodDirector - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
DEBUG 2013-12-30 16:50:05,421 [AWT-EventQueue-0] : HttpMethodDirector - Malformed reply from SOCKS server
java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:706)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:386)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at eltrack.src.PostSync.init(PostSync.java:48)
    at eltrack.EltrackView.startDataPosting(EltrackView.java:367)
    at eltrack.EltrackView.<init>(EltrackView.java:36)
    at eltrack.EltrackApp.startup(EltrackApp.java:19)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below links for proxy configuration in HTTPClient:

[Common HTTPclient and proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811828/common-httpclient-and-proxy)
[Apache HttpClient 4.1 - Proxy Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955644/apache-httpclient-4-1-proxy-settings)

Comment: Set System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "IP Address"); 
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "port"); and try.