# Read time out in Apache HTTP Client but request runs fine with curl

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient, blackduck

- I have a PUT requests that is done by a dependency scanner we are using
- I'm behind a corporate proxy
- Request is done with Apache HTTP Client 4
- I get a "read time out" after the configured timeout
- I recreated the request with curl and this works fine (with the same proxy) and finishes within seconds
- It works fine with Apache HTTP Client without the proxy.

So I'm trying to find out what config is missing in the HTTP client config or what else could be the error. Unfortunately neither our networking team nor the product vendor could help me out :-(

This is the curl request:

```
curl --connect-timeout 60 -m 60 -v -X PUT --data-binary @test.json 
https://someblackduckserver/api/developer-scans/12345 
-H "Content-type: application/vnd.blackducksoftware.developer-scan-1-ld-2+json" 
-H "X-BD-DOCUMENT-COUNT: 1" 
-H "Accept: application/vnd.blackducksoftware.scan-4+json" 
-H "X-BD-MODE: append" 
-H "X-BD-RAPID-SCAN-MODE: ALL" -H "X-BD-VERSION-NAME: scan-test" 
-H "User-Agent: synopsys_detect/8.1.0-SNAPSHOT BlackDuckCommon/65.0.0 ..." 
-H "X-BD-PROJECT-NAME: scan-test" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer ..... left out ....."
```

Where test.json is a json file with about 1.3MB.

Minified code when using Apache HTTP Client:

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = RequestBuilder.create("PUT");
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(new URI("https://someblackduckserver/api/developer-scans/12345"));
requestBuilder.setUri(uriBuilder.build());

Charset bodyEncoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
requestBuilder.setCharset(bodyEncoding);

requestBuilder.addHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.blackducksoftware.developer-scan-1-ld-2+json");
requestBuilder.addHeader("X-BD-DOCUMENT-COUNT", "1");
requestBuilder.addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.blackducksoftware.scan-4+json");
requestBuilder.addHeader("X-BD-MODE", "append");
requestBuilder.addHeader("X-BD-RAPID-SCAN-MODE", "ALL");
requestBuilder.addHeader("X-BD-VERSION-NAME", "scan-test");
requestBuilder.addHeader("User-Agent", "synopsys_detect/8.1.0-SNAPSHOT BlackDuckCommon/65.0.0 ...");
requestBuilder.addHeader("X-BD-PROJECT-NAME", "scan-test");
requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ..... left out .....");

HttpEntity httpEntity = new FileEntity(new File("test.json"));
requestBuilder.setEntity(httpEntity);

HttpUriRequest request = requestBuilder.build();

HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();

HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

RequestConfig.Builder defaultRequestConfigBuilder = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD);
// set our proxy
defaultRequestConfigBuilder.setProxy(new HttpHost("..... (left out)", 8080));

// set timeout
int timeoutInSeconds = 60;
defaultRequestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(timeoutInSeconds * 1000);
defaultRequestConfigBuilder.setSocketTimeout(timeoutInSeconds * 1000);
defaultRequestConfigBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeoutInSeconds * 1000);

clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfigBuilder.build());

// for testing: ignore ssl
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier;
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create().loadTrustMaterial(new TrustAllStrategy()).build();
hostnameVerifier = new NoopHostnameVerifier();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory connectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);
clientBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(connectionFactory);

try (CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build()) {

    CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = client.execute(request, httpContext);

    System.out.println(closeableHttpResponse);
}
```

I removed some sensitive details from the request.

Any idea what I'm missing here or what could go wrong?

Logs from a sample the call:

```
2022-07-25 10:38:38.201 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
2022-07-25 10:38:38.206 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
2022-07-25 10:38:38.207 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {tls}->http://our.proxy.ip.address:8080->https://someblackduckserver.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2022-07-25 10:38:38.259 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {tls}->http://our.proxy.ip.address:8080->https://someblackduckserver.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2022-07-25 10:38:38.260 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {tls}->http://our.proxy.ip.address:8080->https://someblackduckserver.com:443
2022-07-25 10:38:38.261 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to /our.proxy.ip.address:8080
2022-07-25 10:38:38.301 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 10.17.10.44:34272<->our.proxy.ip.address:8080
2022-07-25 10:38:38.317 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> CONNECT someblackduckserver.com:443 HTTP/1.1
2022-07-25 10:38:38.317 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: someblackduckserver.com
2022-07-25 10:38:38.317 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.13)
2022-07-25 10:38:38.317 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "CONNECT someblackduckserver.com:443 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:38.317 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: someblackduckserver.com[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:38.317 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.13)[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:38.317 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:38.346 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:38.346 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Proxy-Agent: Proxy-Vendor-Proxy/1.0[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:38.346 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:38.347 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
2022-07-25 10:38:38.347 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Proxy-Agent: Proxy-Vendor-Proxy/1.0
2022-07-25 10:38:38.347 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Tunnel to target created.
2022-07-25 10:38:38.432 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
2022-07-25 10:38:38.440 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2022-07-25 10:38:38.440 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
2022-07-25 10:38:39.252 [main] DEBUG jdk.event.security - X509Certificate: ... our ssl inspect certificate ...
2022-07-25 10:38:39.252 [main] DEBUG jdk.event.security - X509Certificate: ... our internal certificate ...
2022-07-25 10:38:39.275 [main] DEBUG jdk.event.security -  TLSHandshake: someblackduckserver.com:8080, TLSv1.2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 1942523025
2022-07-25 10:38:39.276 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
2022-07-25 10:38:39.276 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2022-07-25 10:38:39.276 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
2022-07-25 10:38:39.276 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=*.someblackduckserver.com, O="Synopsys, Inc.", L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
2022-07-25 10:38:39.276 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [*.someblackduckserver.com]
2022-07-25 10:38:39.276 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.s.SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: ... our ssl inspect certificate ...
2022-07-25 10:38:39.276 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 60000
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request PUT /api/developer-scans/12345 HTTP/1.1
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> PUT /api/developer-scans/12345 HTTP/1.1
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-type: application/vnd.blackducksoftware.developer-scan-1-ld-2+json
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> X-BD-DOCUMENT-COUNT: 1
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: application/vnd.blackducksoftware.scan-4+json
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> X-BD-MODE: append
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> X-BD-RAPID-SCAN-MODE: ALL
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> X-BD-VERSION-NAME: rapid-scan-test-igl-2
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: synopsys_detect/8.1.0-SNAPSHOT BlackDuckCommon/65.0.0 (Eclipse Foundation 11.0.12 amd64 Windows 10 10.0)
2022-07-25 10:38:39.277 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> X-BD-PROJECT-NAME: project_name
2022-07-25 10:38:39.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: Bearer ...
2022-07-25 10:38:39.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 287381
2022-07-25 10:38:39.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: someblackduckserver.com
2022-07-25 10:38:39.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2022-07-25 10:38:39.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2022-07-25 10:38:39.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "PUT /api/developer-scans/12345 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-type: application/vnd.blackducksoftware.developer-scan-1-ld-2+json[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.278 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "X-BD-DOCUMENT-COUNT: 1[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: application/vnd.blackducksoftware.scan-4+json[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "X-BD-MODE: append[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "X-BD-RAPID-SCAN-MODE: ALL[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "X-BD-VERSION-NAME: rapid-scan-test-igl-2[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: synopsys_detect/8.1.0-SNAPSHOT BlackDuckCommon/65.0.0 (Eclipse Foundation 11.0.12 amd64 Windows 10 10.0)[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "X-BD-PROJECT-NAME: project_name[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: Bearer ...[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 287381[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: someblackduckserver.com[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2022-07-25 10:38:39.279 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"

2022-07-25 10:38:39.423 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> .... all the logs for file content ....

2022-07-25 10:39:39.483 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
2022-07-25 10:39:39.483 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
2022-07-25 10:39:39.483 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
2022-07-25 10:39:39.483 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
2022-07-25 10:39:39.483 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {tls}->http://our.proxy.ip.address:8080->https://someblackduckserver.com:443][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2022-07-25 10:39:39.484 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager is shutting down
2022-07-25 10:39:39.484 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager shut down
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1318)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:959)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingInputStream.read(LoggingInputStream.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.example.BdTest.main(BdTest.java:93)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the corporate proxy? You could also try out another http client like OkHttp, or even just the plain Java Http(s)URLConnection. Another idea is to log as much detail as possible using the Apache logging components and to find out the exact difference between the CURL statement and the Apache client request.

Comment: could you please add a stacktrace?

Comment: did you try setting a very high timeout? did it go through?

Comment: Is the corporate proxy a transparent proxy or is it configured system-wide somehow?

Comment: @vladtkachuk I added the stacktrace. I changed the timeout to 20 minutes, no change.

Comment: @Sebu I'll try to find out more about the proxy we are using. I already started to compare the verbose curl output and the logs. I get the same error when using HttpURLConnection.

Comment: `defaultRequestConfigBuilder.setProxy(new HttpHost("..... (left out)", 8080));` I do not see why this is required. I think it's the problem. There is nothing about this in the curl command. Can you remove the line?

Comment: The proxy is configured as env. variable, so curl picks it up per default. Without the proxy I don't get an internet connection.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually reading the HTTP response - it might not be empty?

Comment: Analyzed you log: it seems that SSL connection is on, but there are two line strange to me. the first is the `CONNECT to someblackduckserver.com:443` (right), but later I see that the handshake is with `TLSHandshake: someblackduckserver.com:8080` (wrong). It could be a proxy misconfguration that change the destination port. Could you check if someblackduckserver.com accept ssl connection on port 8080? If yes, it explains why SSL is went on but no response is received.

Comment: did you try with: `DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(new HttpHost(proxy ip, proxy port));
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();` here is a useful link https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-advanced-config and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955644/apache-httpclient-4-1-proxy-settings

Answer (score -1):

May be not a solution but a workaround if it works. I wrote my own Http client that is much simpler than Apache Http client. The reason I wrote it is that in many cases you just need a simplistic functionality so using a thin library lessens complexity and allows you to debug it if need be and it would allow you easier way to get to the bottom of the problem. So, may be you can give it a shot. At may even work or if not than it would be much easier to debug than Apache Http client. My Http client is part of MgntUtils Open-Source library written and maintained by me. Here is [HttpClient](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html) Javadoc. The library can be obtained as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) from Maven Central and from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to either find out what's wrong with our proxy or to tell the vendor what they need to change in their usage of Apache HTTPClient. I don't think they will switch to a complete different framework for their http calls.

Comment: @TomStroemer, well if you test it with my client and it doesn't work you may have easier time to debug and see the root cause

Comment: I already tried with direct use of HttpUrlConnection with the same result. I also tried your library and get the same result.

Comment: Well, with either one you probably can debug and see where the problem is easier then with Apache. However, obviously the problem is not in Apache. I would use a sniffer something like fiddler to see the difference between request from curl and yours.

Comment: May be your JVM is lacking a certificate and your curl has it. I think that you might be stuck in a handshake.

Comment: Lookup keytool that should be in your bin folder in jdk installation or look up this: http://www.benmccann.com/creating-asc-signature-files-with-gpg/ It might help